# Heroku Error Cannot GET / Node/Express/Router

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment, express-router

I am hosting postgres database and app on Heroku. Express Router was working on my local host. Since I have deployed to Heroku I get ERROR on index route. But URL routes work when typed in.

I have tried making sure the PORT is setup correctly.
I have tried testing to see if Express/Router actually works by changing routes.
I have tried the other answers on stack overflow.
I have checked my proct file.

**app.js**

````
```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

const mustacheExpress = require("mustache-express")

const blogsRouter = require('./routes/blogs')

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

const VIEWS_PATH = path.join(__dirname, '/views')

app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + '/css'))

app.engine("mustache", mustacheExpress(VIEWS_PATH + '/partials', '.mustache'))
app.set("views", VIEWS_PATH)
app.set("view engine", "mustache")

app.use('/blogs', blogsRouter)

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Hey Nick the server is running...")
})```
````

**blogs.js** //Routes folder

````
```const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const SALT_ROUNDS = 10
const session = require('express-session')
const checkAuth = require("../utils/checkAuth")

const pgp = require('pg-promise')();
const connectionString = '#postgress host string is here'
const db = pgp(connectionString);
```
````

Do not know whats causing Express Router not to work on Heroku.

Comment: what was the error you have gotten?

Comment: I did not have a "/" route in my routers folder to handle the route that Heroku was taking me too.

Comment: perhaps try to setup a "/" route that returns an "OK string or something? Could be Heroku doing a health check to make sure the server it up